# Must an async operation callback be run only once?

Tags: javascript

It is squarely [specified](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-26) the Promise/A+ callbacks (`onFulfilled` and `onRejected`) must be run only once and at most one of them can be run, in the other hand.

When we write async js code in the "classical" callback style (`asyncOperation(cb)`), are there any guarantees (probably rested on some de facto conventions) the `cb` would be executed only once? In the other words, in practice, if we deal with a library provided from someone whose conventions we are not aware of and we are strongly descouraged an async operation callback would run more than once, is it our concern to take evasive actions?

Comment: It depends on the API. Event handlers are a form of asynchronous callback, and clearly they can be called more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When we write async js code in the "classical" callback style (asyncOperation(cb)), are there any guarantees (probably rested on some de facto conventions) the cb would be executed only once?

No. See, for example, `setInterval` or `onReadyStateChange`.

> In the other words, in practice, if we deal with a library provided from someone whose conventions we are not aware of and we are strongly descouraged an async operation callback would run more than once, is it our concern to take evasive actions?

In practice, you should read the documentation and understand what the library is doing.